# Visual Basic Progressbar while Copy

Tags: vb.net

As in the Title, i want to have a progressbar, which is showing the process while copying.

My code so far:

Imports System.IO
Imports Scripting

Public Class Form1
    Dim Source, Destination As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject = New FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceSize As Double

```
Private Sub ResetThings()
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xFilesCount = Directory.GetFiles(Source).Length
    Dim xFilesTransferred As Integer = 0

    For Each xFiles In Directory.GetFiles(Source)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Source, Destination, True)
        xFilesTransferred += 1
        ProgressBar1.Value = xFilesTransferred * 100 / xFilesCount
        ProgressBar1.Update()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Source = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    first.Text = "Original: " & Source
    ResetThings()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Destination = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    Dim Temp = Source
    Do
        Temp = Temp.Substring(1)
    Loop Until Temp.Contains("\") = False
    Destination = Destination
    Second.Text = "Ziel: " & Destination

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you having trouble on?

Comment: The progressbar isnt showing anything. But the files are copying...

Comment: I would suggest by looking at it, that you need to set the `ProgressBar1.Maximum`.  and then you can use this line `ProgressBar1.Increment(1)` to make it go up by one after every file. and because you have set a maximum, once all files are done the progress bar should be complete

Comment: Okay thanks.. but how do i use ProgressBar1.Maximum and ProgressBar1.Increment(1) with my code? First time with progressbars :)

Comment: Problem is that you don't copy files, but entire directory - this is single command and doesn't refresh anything.

Comment: so how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Source, Destination, True)` is a synchronous call which blocks the UI and prohibits any interaction as long as you copy all contents of the source directory to the target directory.

You need to:

1. break down the Copy process to copy single files rather then the
   whole directory
2. make the Copy process async to keep the UI responsive and allow the
   ProgrressBar to be updated.

For the first goal use `File.Copy(soruceFile, destinationFile)` in a loop for each file in a directory, like:

```
For Each xFileWithPath In Directory.GetFiles(Source)
     Dim xFile As String = Path.GetFileName(xFileWithPath)
     Try
         File.Copy(xFileWithPath, Path.Combine(Destination, xFile))
         //...
     Catch ex As Exception
          //something went wrong
      End Try
 Next
```

For the second one use a `BackgroundWorker` and set the required properties + event handler:

```
 Dim bw As New BackgroundWorker()
 bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
 AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf copyFiles
 AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf updateUI
```

`DoWork` is the task the BackgroundWorker executes.
`ProgressChanged` is the event raised which you want to subscribe to update your ProgressBar.

`updateUI` could look like:

```
Private Sub updateUI(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        ProgressBar1.Update()
End Sub
```

`copyFiles` combines the copy part + progress update part:

```
 Private Sub copyFiles(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim xFilesCount = Directory.GetFiles(Source).Length
        For Each xFileWithPath In Directory.GetFiles(Source)
            Dim xFile As String = Path.GetFileName(xFileWithPath)
            Try
                File.Copy(xFileWithPath, Path.Combine(Destination, xFile))
                xFilesTransferred += 1
                bw.ReportProgress(xFilesTransferred * 100 / xFilesCount)
            Catch ex As Exception
                 //Something went wrong
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

Eventually you have to start the BackgroundWorker in your button click event:

```
 bw.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Edit:
If you want to copy all files of all sub-directories include `SearchOption.AllDirectories` as last parameter to `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: Thank you very much.. but i dont have much experiences with vb. Could you may give me the whole script like in one file?

Comment: No. You wouldn´t learn anything if I do the coding for you. Especially if you don´t have much experience. Just tell me which part you din´t understand or with what you struggle and I´ll be glad to help pushing you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Due to new information in the comment thread, I've updated my answer.

I've tested this and it worked on my computer. I've changed it now so that you read in the total amount of files in your directory as the maximum and now you are looping through each file in your source directory and copying over the files and keeping track and the progressbar updates.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xFilesCount = Directory.GetFiles(source).Length
    Dim xFilesTransferred As Integer = 0

    ProgressBar1.Maximum = xFilesCount

    For Each xFiles In Directory.GetFiles(source)
        Dim fileinfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(xFiles)
        System.IO.File.Copy(xFiles, Path.Combine(Destination, fileinfo.Name), True)
        xFilesTransferred += 1
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        ProgressBar1.Refresh()
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want do more directories you can loop through directories using recursion or by looping through. I assume you are creating a back up program, this link might be useful: [Using Recursion To Create A Program To Backup Folders](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/395466-using-recursion-to-create-a-program-to-backup-folders/)

Comment: Tanks, but the progressbar isnt showing anything.. maybe i have to edit something in the progressbar properties

Comment: I've been reading up, In your Progress bar properties set the STEP property to the same size as the INCREMENT that you are making. Source: [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420027/progressbar-not-updating-vb-net)

Comment: the Step property is on 10

Comment: The step property should be on 1, as thats how much you are implementing by

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: I think it has something to do with what Arvo in the comments has mentioned. I missed this bit. Are you copying the direcortory or files?

Comment: I am Copying the whole directoy. The programm should copy directorys.

Comment: Change the `ProgressBar1.Maximum` to the total of directories you are copying not files you are copying

Comment: @bigMre The main problem is not the `ProgressBar.Maximum` or `Minimum` values. The problem is the synchronous call of CopyDirectory which blocks the UI and thus the ProgressBar. See my answer.

Comment: This code doesn't work as you're still copying the entire directory using `CopyDirectory`.